# Current day + N days

Tags: crystal-reports

My formula shows today date + 2 days. It was working fine until yesterday, but since the month ends soon the formula is incorrect.

```
If Not HasValue({?Start Date})
Then ToNumber(ToText(CurrentDate, 'yyyyMMdd')) + 2 
Else ToNumber(ToText({?Start Date}, 'yyyyMMdd'))
```

How can I get the proper result?

Comment: May you give an example that you can reproduce? Tell us the input, the observed output and the desired output. Anyways, you can use dateadd('d',2,currentdate).

Comment: Thank you Heringer for the reply. I have tried this before and this formula gives me an error "A date-time is required here". My challenge is to convert date field to the text format and then add two days within it.  Here is the formula you have advised:If not hasvalue({?Start Date}) then tonumber(totext(currentdate,'yyyyMMdd'))+ dateadd('d',2,currentdate)
   else tonumber(totext({?Start Date},'yyyyMMdd'))

Comment: As Ihave stated before formula had some issues at the end of the month otherwise it works great. Thx

Comment: Is {?Start Date} a string? If so, it would explain the error "A date-time is required here". So, there are two workarounds. First would be convert {?Start Date} to date. Second would be convert currentdate to string *after* the operation: totext(dateadd('d',2,currentdate)). But maybe i did not understand the point, i will drop it.

Comment: Thank you Heringer. for your help. The Start date was a string. After converting to date, it was hunky-dory.

Comment: Glad it helped. I will "move" the comment to an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Since {?Start Date} was a string, as confirmed in the comments, it explains the error "A date-time is required here".

So, there are two workarounds.

First would be convert {?Start Date} to date.

Second would be convert currentdate to string after the operation: totext(dateadd('d',2,currentdate)).

user10376573 confirmed that the first workaround did the job.